# Extract a sequence from a string in java using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a log with a pattern . The thing is in the last it is a little bit different from regular .

```
a>  nc,71802265,0,"Tuesday, June 26, 2012 09:06:49 UTC",38.8335,-122.8072,1.6,0.00,21,"Northern California"
b>  ci,11127314,0,"Tuesday, June 26, 2012 08:37:52 UTC",34.2870,-118.3360,2.2,10.20,100,"Greater Los Angeles area, California"
c>  us,b000aqpn,6,"Tuesday, June 26, 2012 08:29:55 UTC",53.4819,-165.2794,4.4,25.60,96,"Fox Islands, Aleutian Islands, Alaska"

String regex = "^\\"[a-z,A-Z]\\s*\\(,)*[a-z,A-Z]\\"";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

from a I need --- "Northern California"
from b I need --- "Greater Los Angeles area, California" and so on

Thanks

Comment: You just want the string within the last pair of double quotes? You don't necessarily need a Regex for this.

Comment: Yes , preciesely. How come. Any hint or idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, precisely what? :P As said, you don't need a regex for such a simple task. For example, check [StringTokenizer class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Comment: @ m0skit0 I know about StringTokenizer class. Cant use it. Check the pattern , cant use the delimiter as ",";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`String#lastIndexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), starting from the penultimate character to find the first `"`:

```
    String s = "a>  nc,71802265,0,\"Tuesday, June 26, 2012 09:06:49 UTC\",38.8335,-122.8072,1.6,0.00,21,\"Northern California\"";
    int start = s.lastIndexOf("\"", s.length() - 2) + 1;
    String location = s.substring(start, s.length() - 1);
```

Comment: Its not a simple string. I am getting the input as a streams of data from multiple source.Thats the problem .

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [String.split(regex, limit)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and specify the number of commas you need to split on.

That way you can get the last field *intact with commas*, and then simply strip the double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$` anchor to tell that your match should be at the end of the line:

```
String lines = "a>  nc,71802265,0,\"Tuesday, June 26, 2012 09:06:49 UTC\",38.8335,-122.8072,1.6,0.00,21,\"Northern California\"\nb>  ci,11127314,0,\"Tuesday, June 26, 2012 08:37:52 UTC\",34.2870,-118.3360,2.2,10.20,100,\"Greater Los Angeles area, California\"\nc>  us,b000aqpn,6,\"Tuesday, June 26, 2012 08:29:55 UTC\",53.4819,-165.2794,4.4,25.60,96,\"Fox Islands, Aleutian Islands, Alaska\"";
    String regex = "\"[^\"]*\"$";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(lines);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

outputs:

```
"Northern California"
"Greater Los Angeles area, California"
"Fox Islands, Aleutian Islands, Alaska"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(String s: log.split("\n")){
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll(".+(\".+\")$","$1"));
 }
```